# Analyzing data in a list of lists and extracting the wanted information in Python

Tags: python

We have two lists of lists: the first one is a list of 5 NBA teams and their three letter codes, and the
second is a list of games between teams. For example the third game ['MIL', 'TOR', 129, 111] is
between the Bucks and the Raptors. Bucks is the home team, Raptors is the away team, Bucks won
the game 129 to 111.

```
T = [['TOR', 'Toronto Raptors' ],
['BOS', 'Boston Celtics' ],
['CHI', 'Chicago Bulls' ],
['MIL', 'Milwaukee Bucks' ],
['MIN', 'Minnesota Timberwolves']]

G = [['CHI', 'TOR', 119, 123],
['CHI', 'MIN', 122, 123],
['MIL', 'TOR', 129, 111],
['MIL', 'MIN', 105, 118],
['MIL', 'BOS', 101, 105],
['MIN', 'CHI', 112, 125],
['BOS', 'CHI', 123, 103]]
```

How do I extract the desired data and print it in this format:

```
                         N H A W L
 Toronto Raptors         2 0 2 1 1
 Boston Celtics          2 2 0 1 1
 Chicago Bulls           4 2 2 1 3
 Milwaukee Bucks         3 2 1 3 0
 Minnesota Timberwolves  3 1 2 1 2
```

where "N" is the number of games played, "H" home games, "A" away games, "W" wins, "L" losses

This is my initial approach to the problem. But as you can see, the output isn't very fancy and the method is pretty tedious. I was wondering if there were a better way to go about solving the problem. One that outputs using the aforementioned format, perhaps?

```
loss_TOR = 0
loss_MIN = 0
loss_MIL = 0
loss_BOS = 0
loss_CHI = 0

win_CHI = 0
win_TOR = 0
win_MIN = 0
win_MIL = 0
win_BOS = 0

home_CHI = 0
home_TOR = 0
home_MIN = 0
home_MIL = 0
home_BOS = 0

away_CHI = 0
away_TOR = 0
away_MIN = 0
away_MIL = 0
away_BOS = 0


TOR = 'Toronto Raptors'
BOS = 'Boston Celtics'
CHI = 'Chicago Bulls'
MIL = 'Milwaukee Bucks'
MIN = 'Minnesota Timberwolves'

T = [['TOR', 'Toronto Raptors' ],
    ['BOS', 'Boston Celtics' ],
    ['CHI', 'Chicago Bulls' ],
    ['MIL', 'Milwaukee Bucks' ],
    ['MIN', 'Minnesota Timberwolves']]

G = [['CHI', 'TOR', 119, 123],
    ['CHI', 'MIN', 122, 123],
    ['MIL', 'TOR', 129, 111],
    ['MIL', 'MIN', 105, 118],
    ['MIL', 'BOS', 101, 105],
    ['MIN', 'CHI', 112, 125],
    ['BOS', 'CHI', 123, 103]]

X = G
for i in range(len(X)):
    if int(X[i][-1]) > int(X[i][-2]):

        if X[i][-3] == "CHI":
            win_CHI += 1

        elif X[i][-3] == "TOR":
            win_TOR += 1

        elif X[i][-3] == "MIN":
            win_MIN += 1

        elif X[i][-3] == "MIL":
            win_MIL += 1 

        elif X[i][-3] == "BOS":
            win_BOS += 1
    elif int(X[i][-2]) > int(X[i][-1]):


        if X[i][-4] == "CHI":
            win_CHI += 1

        elif X[i][-4] == "TOR":
            win_TOR += 1

        elif X[i][-4] == "MIN":
            win_MIN += 1

        elif X[i][-4] == "MIL":
            win_MIL += 1 

        elif X[i][-4] == "BOS":
            win_BOS += 1



for i in range(len(X)):
    if int(X[i][-1]) > int(X[i][-2]):

        if X[i][-4] == "CHI":
            loss_CHI += 1

        elif X[i][-4] == "TOR":
            loss_TOR += 1

        elif X[i][-4] == "MIN":
            loss_MIN += 1

        elif X[i][-4] == "MIL":
            loss_MIL += 1 

        elif X[i][-4] == "BOS":
            loss_BOS += 1
    elif int(X[i][-2]) > int(X[i][-1]):


        if X[i][-3] == "CHI":
            loss_CHI += 1

        elif X[i][-3] == "TOR":
            loss_TOR += 1

        elif X[i][-3] == "MIN":
            loss_MIN += 1

        elif X[i][-3] == "MIL":
            loss_MIL += 1 

        elif X[i][-3] == "BOS":
            loss_BOS += 1

for i in range(len(X)):
    if str(G[i][-4]) == "CHI":
        home_CHI += 1
    elif str(G[i][-4]) == "TOR":
        home_TOR += 1
    elif str(G[i][-4]) == "MIN":
        home_MIN += 1
    elif str(G[i][-4]) == "MIL":
        home_MIL += 1
    elif str(G[i][-4]) == "BOS":
        home_BOS += 1

for i in range(len(X)):
    if str(G[i][-3]) == "CHI":
        away_CHI += 1
    elif str(G[i][-3]) == "TOR":
        away_TOR += 1
    elif str(G[i][-3]) == "MIN":
        away_MIN += 1
    elif str(G[i][-3]) == "MIL":
        away_MIL += 1
    elif str(G[i][-3]) == "BOS":
        away_BOS += 1


tot_CHI = home_CHI + away_CHI
tot_TOR = home_TOR + away_TOR
tot_MIN = home_MIN + away_MIN
tot_MIL = home_MIL + away_MIL
tot_BOS = home_BOS + away_BOS

print("Number of Games:")
print("{} {}".format(tot_TOR, TOR))
print("{} {}".format(tot_BOS, BOS))
print("{} {}".format(tot_CHI, CHI))
print("{} {}".format(tot_MIL, MIL))
print("{} {}".format(tot_MIN, MIN))
print()
print()
print("Number of Home & Away Games:")
print("{} {} {}".format(home_TOR, away_TOR, TOR))
print("{} {} {}".format(home_BOS, away_BOS, BOS))
print("{} {} {}".format(home_CHI, away_CHI, CHI))
print("{} {} {}".format(home_MIL, away_MIL, MIL))
print("{} {} {}".format(home_MIN, away_MIN, MIN))
print()
print()
print("Number of Wins & Losses: ")
print("{} {} {}".format(win_TOR, loss_TOR, TOR))
print("{} {} {}".format(win_BOS, loss_BOS, BOS))
print("{} {} {}".format(win_CHI, loss_CHI, CHI))
print("{} {} {}".format(win_MIL, loss_MIL, MIL))
print("{} {} {}".format(win_MIN, loss_MIN, MIN))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems,** and code to reproduce it**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Sorry, we can't solve your homework questions and give you code in hands, show us what have you done and your approach, read https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: I have tried a very tedious approach that works but isn't very beautiful. I made variables for each possible case for example: num_away_games_TOR = 0   and incremented 1 by using a for loop that checks index values... wait I'll post my actual code.

Comment: @Agent_Orange I am currently self studying Python and am just trying to see if there's a better way to solve this problem. I understand where you're coming from though. But this is a problem of not knowing enough, rather than knowing and not bothering to try. Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
T = [['TOR', 'Toronto Raptors' ],
['BOS', 'Boston Celtics' ],
['CHI', 'Chicago Bulls' ],
['MIL', 'Milwaukee Bucks' ],
['MIN', 'Minnesota Timberwolves']]

G = [['CHI', 'TOR', 119, 123],
['CHI', 'MIN', 122, 123],
['MIL', 'TOR', 129, 111],
['MIL', 'MIN', 105, 118],
['MIL', 'BOS', 101, 105],
['MIN', 'CHI', 112, 125],
['BOS', 'CHI', 123, 103]]

nameMap = {i[0]:i[1] for i in T}
data = {i[0]:{'N':0,'H':0,'A':0,'W':0,'L':0} for i in T}

for i in G:
    data[i[0]]['H']+=1
    data[i[1]]['A']+=1

    data[i[0]]['N']+=1
    data[i[1]]['N']+=1

    if i[2]>i[3]:
        data[i[0]]['W']+=1
        data[i[1]]['L']+=1
    else:
        data[i[1]]['W']+=1
        data[i[0]]['L']+=1
for i,(k,v) in enumerate(data.items()):
    print(nameMap[k], v['N'], v['H'], v['A'], v['W'], v['L'],)
```

```
Toronto Raptors 2 0 2 1 1
Boston Celtics 2 1 1 2 0
Chicago Bulls 4 2 2 1 3
Milwaukee Bucks 3 3 0 1 2
Minnesota Timberwolves 3 1 2 2 1
```

For even more fancy output

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.transpose().head()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'll review the documentation for dictionaries and come back if I have any questions.

Comment: yes, it did. Though I don't understand what this pandas module does and where I should put it. Do you think you could explain to me? I think I should put it after the data variable declaration

Comment: pandas is a library for data handling, it is absolutely not required here.
 If you want to read more about it https://pandas.pydata.org/